# Codeigniter & Gmaps v3 example

Tags: xml, ajax, codeigniter, maps

I use this http://goo.gl/d3vLW code for my project, but it's not working the way how I want it.
Using Codeigniter I just modified the **downloadUrl** function phpsqlajax_genxml.php to controller/method

The problem: if I use *header("Content-type: text/xml");* in the method, I get the following error:

```
XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: http://localhost/website/
Line Number 3, Column 1:<!DOCTYPE html>
^
```

Viewing the source code the generated xml is before my template php html tag...

If I comment out the header() , I get no markers on the map.

If I add the following line

```
request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
```

in the javascript part of the code to the end of downloadURL function, markers are there, page is working successful, **but why I have the xml again before the template php html tag**?

As I guess, the php method should pass the generated xml to the javascript function, but not in "visible mode", hmm?

So..

1. why I get error using header() - as in the example - in my method?
2. If I stuck with te second solution that works, how to pass xml without storing it before the template file html tag? It's ugly and increase file size..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you have output the XML in the controller method, and then load the view? I'm just guessing, you didn't post the whole code?

Comment: hmm so what you suggest? this controller is a javascript called callback, so doesn't use view.

Comment: Could you post the whole code so I could get a better insight what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: the example is in the first row of my question. no i plan to change all the xml things to json